# Using curl to query etherscan API, gets "rate limit of 1/5sec applied" error

Tags: etherscan

When I input https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xafdcdf23b2bfdae668a825630340c48eca9a7598e205a0291de1db05c1231926&apikey=MY_KEY in browser and press return, I will get correct response.

But when I input: **curl** https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xafdcdf23b2bfdae668a825630340c48eca9a7598e205a0291de1db05c1231926&apikey=MY_KEY in my command window, I got below error:

[1] 2122 
[2] 2123 
[3] 2124 
[2]-  Done                    action=eth_getTransactionByHash 
[3]+  Done                    txhash=0xafdcdf23b2bfdae668a825630340c48eca9a7598e205a0291de1db05c1231926 
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK-Missing/Invalid API Key, rate limit of 1/5sec applied","result":"Error! Missing Or invalid Action name"}

I think it is because **curl** requested etherscan API more than 5 times per second, which caused this error. How can I avoid this?

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try registering to get your own apikey?

Comment: Yes, I used "MY_KEY" in my question, but in reality, it is my real key, otherwise I won't be able to get correct response when I keyed it in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your curl command needs some quoting, as the result indicates 3 different shell processes:

```
[1] 2122
[2] 2123
[3] 2124
[2]- Done action=eth_getTransactionByHash
[3]+ Done txhash=0xafdcdf23b2bfdae668a825630340c48eca9a7598e205a0291de1db05c1231926
{"status":"0","message":"NOTOK-Missing/Invalid API Key, rate limit of 1/5sec applied","result":"Error! Missing Or invalid Action name"}
```

Try your command like this (two commands in sequence) :

```
MY_KEY="<your_actual_key>"

curl "https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xafdcdf23b2bfdae668a825630340c48eca9a7598e205a0291de1db05c1231926&apikey=$MY_KEY"
```

Please use the double quotes in both for your shell interpolate correctly your environment variable.